# Overloading R function - is this right?

Tags: r, overloading

```
consumeSingleRequest <- function(api_key, URL, columnNames, globalParam="", ...) 
consumeSingleRequest <- function(api_key, URL, columnNames, valuesList, globalParam="")
```

I am trying to overload a function like this, that takes in multiple lists in the first function and combines them into one list of lists. However, I don't seem to be able to skip passing in globalParam and pass in oly the multiple lists in the ...

Does anyone know how to do that?

I've heard S3 methods could be used for that? Does anyone know how?

Comment: S3 methods are used to call different function depending on class of passed arguments, not a number of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R doesn't support a concept of overloading functions. It supports function calls with variable number of arguments. So you can declare a function with any number of arguments, but supply only a subset of those when actually calling a function. Take `vector` function as an example:

```
> vector
function (mode = "logical", length = 0L) 
.Internal(vector(mode, length))
<bytecode: 0x103b89070>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

It supports up to 2 parameters, but can be called with none or some subset(in that case default values are used) :

```
> vector()
logical(0)
> vector(mode='numeric')
numeric(0)
```

So you only need a second declaration:

```
consumeSingleRequest <- function(api_key, URL, columnNames, valuesList, globalParam="")
```

And supply just supply the needed parameters when actually calling the function

```
consumeSingleRequest(api_key=..., valueList=...)
```

P.S. A good explanation can be found in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments) Book.

Comment: Hi @romantsegelskyi do you mean that I should call the function twice? What do you mean by second declaration?

Comment: Second declaration - of the declarations you listed